# What is the purpose of nodev?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I'm talking about the mount option. What is it used for? What is the purpose behind preventing device nodes from being created in a filesystem?

Comment: If you have a USB stick that has `/dev/sda` on it and it's owned by your user ID, you can then stick it into the server/desktop and you now have block level access to the hard drive. [For example](https://dpaste.de/abDR)